# asp.net DropDownList inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdownlistfor

I'm using GridView and inside that I have DropDownList

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drop_prod" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drop_prod_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drop_mail" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drop_mail_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Dropdownlist is already populated by values(dynamically) and if user will select some other value from dropdownlist I would like to get that value without postback action.

I hope you will help me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "get that value"?  Do you mean on the server, or on the client?

Comment: On the server would be the best option

Comment: The only way to access it on the server without doing a postback would be through ajax.  You would have to handle the change event in javascript and send that value to the server via an ajax call.

Comment: without having a full postback, the only option is AJAX.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Specifically, what do you want to do with the dropdown value?

Comment: Well, dropdownlist have 5 values and if user will select one value then that value will be updated as default value in database. It is clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I would like to get that value without postback action."*

If you dont want postback at all , you can catch dropdown change event in jquery.

```
<asp:DropDownList  class="dropdown" ID="drop_prod" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drop_prod_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Note class 'dropdown' above.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".dropdown").change(function(){

    var selectedValue= $(this).val();
    $(".ddl-value").val(selectedValue);
});

});
```

**EDIT:**

You can put one hidden variable in page like

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedvalue" runat="server" class="ddl-value"/>
```

on server side access it like :

```
selectedvalue.Value
```

Comment: voteup or mark as answer , if it works for you. Dont forget to include jQuery library.

Comment: So I have tried and nothing happend when I changed value. To be honest I'm newbie in coding asp.net sites so maybe I made just stupid mistake. That is script: <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $(".dropdown").change(function(){

    var selectedValue= $(this).val();
    $(".ddl-value").val(selectedValue);
});

});
    </script>

Comment: have you included jQuery library ?

Comment: Well, I guess yes: <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"> . If I want to access it from server side where I should put selectedvalue.Value ?

Comment: Why would you use a hidden variable?  By default dropdowns don't cause a postback, and the event will eventually fire when a postback occurs.  Any logic can still be handled there.

Comment: Hidden variable that you set in JS can be read on server side as it has runat="server"

Comment: Why not just read the dropdown element itself in the selection changed event?

Comment: Also, if 3 different dropdowns are changed, the hidden element will only contain the last change.

Comment: because its inside gridview , for which row it is how will you know that ?

Comment: If you need changed value of all rows then you will have to post everything via Ajax.

Comment: It depends on what OP's intentions are.  Your solution doesn't store the row either.  Your solution just stores the last value of the last change in a hidden variable instead of using the built in functionality of asp.net.

Comment: Agree you can put all data in json for each row and postback entire json , but why he intends to do by avoiding post back that is not clear

Comment: Your code seems to working, I can read value. Well, I wanted to avoid postback as there is alot of rows and user is able to change each of them - each value in dropdownlist and if there will be postback then that will be very annoying. Lets say that there is 50 rows in gridview, so 50 dropdownlists, each dropdownlist have 5 values, each value have own ID, also each row have own ID so if user changed row with ID: 27 and then he selected value(from dropdownlist) with ID: 3 then in the database his record ID:27 will be updated on: 3

Comment: Create list of ids for which values is changed and post back that list   Learn about ajax post with json and WebMethods. http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/44052-Update-Delete-GridView-using-JQuery-without-page-post-back.aspx    upvote , if you consider my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field with each dropdownlist and set the hidden field value to dropdownlist value using javascript. On submit loop through hidden field and get the value.

Comment: That's not necessary.  If you just set autopostback to false for the dropdowns, the change events will only fire when the form is submitted, not when the selection is changed. The logic can be placed there.